# Change dynamically Text of asp:label by databases data

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have in a databases, a table like this :

|   ID   |   Cod_lang|   Libelle   |

|   52   |   FR         |   Bonjour  |

|   52   |   EN         |   Hello     |

|   53   |   FR         |   Oui      |

|   53   |   EN         |    Yes       |

And I have two  in a .aspx file.

I manage to consult the database with ADO.net but I wish to replace the attribute "Text" in my label with data that I have get in my DB.

In fact, I have a lot of label, but I thinks a little sample with two label is enough.

Do you have an idea please ?

Edit : How I can make an associative table in C# ? With Hashtable ? But with hashtable, How I can get my data by key ?

Comment: Only English is allowed here, update your question ...

Comment: associative array in c# = Dictionary see link below

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward to achieve given that you already have the table above and data coming out of your database and created a form with the controls you mention. However if this is simply a question to ask whether is it **possible**, then the answer is simply Yes.

If you don't know how to proceed show some code.

For the example above your Dictionary would look like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDictionary.Add("FR", "Bonjour");
someLabel.Text = myDictionary["FR"];
```

someLabel will now show "Bonjour"

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;). I thinks it is possible but probably I must use an associative array in C# and for the moment, HashTable seems a good solution...

Comment: If you add some code it will be easier to give more help. A Dictionary  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx ) may be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, for the moment, Dictionnary seems good for me =D.
Can you help me for the next question ?
If I had some labels with id like :
    id="control512"
    id="control1024"
    id="control2048"...
And my dictionnary is :
    ("control512","Hello")
    ("control1024","YES")
    ("control2048","Test")...
How I can change dynamically ma label "Text" with this dictionnary ?

Comment: That code would look like this control512.Text=myDictionary["control512"];

Comment: Yes, but if I had 100 controls, can I use a loop ?

Comment: Sure you can have a loop like foreach (var item in myDictionary){} and inside use item.Key.ToString() to get name of control, then use findControl to find the correct control and assign Text value.

Comment: Thanks ! I think that is the solution =D